# CSS: Height of an fixed Element to the bottom of the viewport

Tags: css

I got an iframe (class:side_bar) on my page, positioned by position:fixed at a point in my textflow. Its top-position may vary from 100-200px. The height of this element should reach the bottom of the viewport, regardless of its content.
I tried height:100vh and height:100%, but then its the height of the whole window, and the elements lower end is cut of by the browser frame.
Is there any way of getting the initial top-position of my element, so that i can use heigh:calc(100%-top-position), or some simple option to stretch that element to the bottom of the browser (not the bottom of the page, since it may be longer)?
Thanks so much (and sorry for my bad english ;) )

Edit: i made a small example - not perfect, but you can see what i mean...

```css
.main
    {
    width:100%;
    }
.header
    {
    width:100%;
    text-align:right;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:1px
    }
.side_bar
    {
    position:fixed;
    width:150px;
    height:100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:1px
    display:inline-block;
    }
.content
    {
    margin-left:150px;
    padding:10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:1px
    }
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="header">
        <b>Header:</b><br>Height may vary, around 100px-200px, depending on content.
        </div> 
    <iframe class="side_bar" srcdoc="
        <b>Side bar:</b>
        <p>Content may vary, sometimes scrolling, sometimes not</p>
        <p>This iframe should end at the bottom of the viewport, and begin below Header - regardless of content</p>
        <p>By scrolling the page if needed, this iframe must stay in place, therefor position:fixed</p>
        <p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p>
        <p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p>
        <p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p>
        "> </iframe>
    <div class="content">
        <b>Main content:</b>
        <p>Content may vary, sometimes scrolling, sometimes not</p>
        <p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p>
        <p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p>
        <p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: By 'bottom of the browser' do you mean 'bottom of the viewport'? Please include basic code to show us the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Your question is super unclear, hope this is what you've wanted

```js
document.querySelector(".content").innerHTML = "<p>content</p>".repeat(60);


const header = document.querySelector(".header");
const sidebar = document.querySelector(".side_bar");
sidebar.style.top = header.offsetHeight + "px";

header.onchange = () => {
  sidebar.style.top = header.offsetHeight + "px";
};
onscroll = () => {
  const diff = header.offsetHeight - window.pageYOffset;
  if (diff < 0) {
    sidebar.style.top = 0;
  } else {
    sidebar.style.top = diff + "px";
  }
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  border: 0.3px solid;
}

section {
  display: flex;
}

.side_bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0.3px solid;
}

.content {
  margin-left: 20vw;
  width: 80vw;
  padding: 1vh;
  border: 0.3px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="header">
    <p>header</p>
  </div>

  <section>
    <iframe class="side_bar" srcdoc="
          <b>Side bar:</b>
          <p>Content may vary, sometimes scrolling, sometimes not</p>
          <p>This DIV should end at the bottom of the viewport, and begin below Header - regardless of content</p>
          <p>By scrolling the page if needed, this DIV must stay in place, therefor position:fixed</p>
          <p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p>
          <p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p>
          <p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p>
          ">
        </iframe>

    <div class="content">
      <b>Main content:</b>
      <p>Content may vary, sometimes scrolling, sometimes not</p>
    </div>
  </section>

</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in my question, i corrected it to make it a little clearer...
The height of .header cannot be set so a specific value, it depends on the content in .header, which is changing.
the only problem is the height of side_bar - if set to height:100%, the lower end ist cut of as in your example.
a workaround would be height:calc(100%-30px) and top:30px, but when .header gets higher, it then will be overlapped...

Comment: @Matthias how about now ?

Comment: No :( now - if you add more content to .content, yout will have to scroll .content to be able to view all the content in .side_bar. .side_bar should stay in place even if the main page is scrolled - both areas should scroll completly independent...

Comment: @Matthias how about now